# jquery getting dynamically generated content from title attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, title

I have a html table    `<table>` with number of columns each column has title attribute which is dynamically generated  via `ajax()` function. I am trying to get content from all the columns of table but the content of title attribute is not showing up,

eg:

```
<table>
   <tr>
       <td id="myid" title="some data generated by ajax() call"> test </td>
   </tr>
  </table>
```

jQuery code :

```
 $(document).ready(
     function(){
        alert($("td#myid").html());


});
```

Comment: Without the other code I can't really say, but maybe try putting that once the Ajax call has completed?

Answer (score 1):

Call this in your `ajax success function` i.e. after the ajax has been executed:

```
alert($("td#myid").attr('title'));
```

.html() gives you the entire html not just the title.

*Also note that for any data received through ajax, you need to access it only after ajax call has been successfully completed. How can you use it on document ready, when ajax call is being fired?*

Answer (score 1):

html returns the innerHtml property
you need to use

```
$("td#myid").attr("title");
```

or

```
$("td#myid").prop("title");
```

depending on your version of jquery.